# Generating SOAP Requests from Java objects

Tags: soap, jaxb

I need to create a Soap request from a request object in Java. What is needed is below :

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <tem:tag1>
        <tem:tag2>
        <MyDataSet>
            <!-- more elements within-->
        </MyDataSet>
        <tem:tag1>
        <tem:tag2>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <atom/>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

However, what I am getting is this :

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <MyDataSet>
            <!-- more elements within-->
        </MyDataSet>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <atom/>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Can someone please tell me how do I add `<tem:tag1>` and `<tem:tag2>` in the soap request ? This is the code that I have written so far:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        MyRequest request = new MyRequest();
        Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
        Marshaller marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyRequest.class).createMarshaller();
        marshaller.marshal(request, document);
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage();
        soapMessage.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().addNamespaceDeclaration("tem", "http://tempuri.org/");
        soapMessage.getSOAPBody().addDocument(document);
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        soapMessage.writeTo(outputStream);
        String output = new String(outputStream.toByteArray());
        System.out.println(output);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that the web service has published WSDL, I suggest that instead of rolling your own client code, you generate it using wsimport, a utility that is included in the Java JDK.  One article on how to use it can be found [here](http://www.thejavageek.com/2015/01/28/using-wsimport-command-generate-web-service-client/).